# Necessary conditions for a partition of $\mathbb{N}$

Tags: number-theory

I need some help with this problem: Given the sets $M_k , k=1,...,\infty$. Each composed by an infinity of natural numbers and such that the Intersection of $M_k$ with $M_p =\emptyset$ for all $k$ and $p$, how can I prove that this is a partition of $\mathbb{N}^*$ (the set of the natural numbers without zero)?

Comment: That would depend on what other information you have about the sets. The information you have given is not enough to prove that they partition the naturals.

Comment: From your statement, you would still be left with showing that every natural number appears in one of the sets $M_k$.  You would need more information about the particular situation to do this.

Comment: thanks Gerry Myerson and paw88789. The problem is that all my efforts to prove that any natural number belongs to one of the Mk have failed. So I wonder if there is another way to prove that the set of Mk is a partition via necessary/sufficient conditions.

Answer (score 1):

If you by parition mean non-overlapping sets whose union is N then this is not correct.

Consider $M_k$ = $\{a \in N : \text{the $k$:th prime is the smalles divisor of a} \}$.
Note that $M_k \cap M_p = \emptyset$ if $p\neq k$ and each set is infinite, however $\cup_{i=1}^\infty M_i \neq N$ since $1$ is not included. 
So here we only have a partial partition.

Comment: Thanks Ove Ahlman. This is exactly my question: which are the necessary conditions that allow me to say that the set of non overlapping sets Mk is a partition of N. Since I have failed to demonstrate that any number k of N belongs to one of the Mk, I wonder if there is a workaround.